# Compatibility of transformers version 4.11.1 with Python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have an issue, while installing transformer version 4.11.1 library. Has anyone encountered it before? It seems like Python library error to me ...

```
    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.9/2.9 MB 10.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 295.0/295.0 kB 14.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 880.6/880.6 kB 19.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
 Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 212.7/212.7 kB 18.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
 Installing build dependencies ... done
 Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
 Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 
 × Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
 │ exit code: 1
 ╰─> See above for output.
 
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
 Building wheel for sacremoses (setup.py) ... done
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```